# What is the source (if any) for using a six-wicked candle for Havdalah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, havdalah

I have often heard that there is a Minhag to use specifically a six-wicked candle for Havdalah to represent the six workdays of the week. However I have not been able to locate a source for this. The only sources I can find mention two wicks as either the proper number or at least the minimum.

Comment: It's befeirush brought down [here](https://www.jewbelong.com/holidays/havdalah/#:~:text=some%20people%20use%20six%20wicks%20to%20represent%20the%20days%20of%20the%20week%20until%20Shabbat).

Comment: While I did come across that "source" the while researching, I'm looking for something a little more authoritative than a website.

Comment: Figured. Personally I've never heard of it, and I couldn't find any other sources.